# Spring forward with added parameters?

Tags: java, spring, controller, forward

Is there a way to forward a request to another Controller while adding some parameter data to it? I tried adding to the ModelMap, but it doesn't seem to hang around. I am doing something like:

```
return "forward:/my-other-controller";
```

Only other way I can think of is to put the parameters on the session and then pop them off in the target controller.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

**The simplest way is to add the data to the request.** Since this is a forward, the same request is passed around to different handlers within the server.

As example, let's start with a simple setup of two controllers, one forwarding to the other:

```
@Controller
public class TestController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/test")
    public String showTestPage() {
        return "forward:/test2";
    }
}

@Controller
public class TestController2 {
    @RequestMapping(value="/test2")
    public String showTestPage() {
        return "testPageView";
    }
}
```

First way to add the data is to set it as attributes on the request. The new controllers will look like this (**A**):

```
@Controller
public class TestController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/test")
    public String showTestPage(HttpServletRequest request) {
        request.setAttribute("param1", "foo");
        request.setAttribute("param2", "bar");
        return "forward:/test2";
    }
}

@Controller
public class TestController2 {
    @RequestMapping(value="/test2")
    public String showTestPage(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String param1 = (String) request.getAttribute("param1");
        String param2 = (String) request.getAttribute("param2");
        return "testPageView";
    }
}
```

Since the view name in the [forward prefix is basically an URL](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/mvc.html#mvc-redirecting-forward-prefix), you can also have the following versions (attribute changed to parameter) (**B**):

```
@Controller
public class TestController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/test")
    public String showTestPage() {
        return "forward:/test2?param1=foo&param2=bar";
    }
}

@Controller
public class TestController2 {
    @RequestMapping(value="/test2")
    public String showTestPage(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String param1 = request.getParameter("param1");
        String param2 = request.getParameter("param2");
        return "testPageView";
    }
}
```

You can also further simplify the second controller by using annotations instead:

```
@Controller
public class TestController2 {
    @RequestMapping(value="/test2")
    public String showTestPage(@RequestParam String param1, @RequestParam String param2) {
        return "testPageView";
    }
}
```

And just for the fun of it, and to show Spring's binding behavior in action, you could do it even like this (**C**):

```
@Controller
public class TestController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/test")
    public String showTestPage() {
        return "forward:/test2?param1=foo&param2=bar";
    }
}

@Controller
public class TestController2 {
    @RequestMapping(value="/test2")
    public String showTestPage(@ModelAttribute DummyBinder params) {
        String param1 = params.getParam1();
        String param2 = params.getParam2();
        return "testPageView";
    }
}

class DummyBinder {
    private String param1;
    private String param2;

    public String getParam1() {
        return param1;
    }

    public void setParam1(String param1) {
        this.param1 = param1;
    }

    public String getParam2() {
        return param2;
    }

    public void setParam2(String param2) {
        this.param2 = param2;
    }
}
```

**I would personally go with solution A for many parameters, and solution B for a few.** Solution C has a sort of "huh...?!" effect so I would avoid it (also it works with parameters added to the URL so a few of those or you get a messy URL).

Adding the data in the session would also work off course, but would extend the data's life time unnecessarily, so the best place is to add it on the request during the transition to the second controller.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! This gets to the heart of my confusion. There are "attributes" and "parameters" all over the place and I never seem to understand which is which. My POST request has binary data in the body, so I can't use that for url-encoded "parameters." So what does request.setAttribute() actually do? Are these just arbitrary key/value pairs that are on the HttpServletRequest object, OR are they stored as actual HTTP parameters, like as a query string  etc.? And what is the difference between request.setAttribute and request.setParameter?

Comment: @Tony R: Parameters are what your user sends when submitting on a  GET/POST. It's mostly read-only data (there is no request.setParameter; the server builds the request object with the parameters inside for you to get). Attributes is data placed in a certain scope at your server. You use request.setAttribute to place data in "request scope" (for ex. you can have also session scope or application scope). You can add attributes, get them, or remove them. Here is a simple explanation: http://www.xyzws.com/Servletfaq/what-is-the-difference-between-the-request-attribute-and-request-parameter/1

Comment: Thanks very much for the explanation. I didn't realize that parameters are read-only, which actually makes perfect sense. Now the answer seems trivial... In fact, I wonder why it took so long to get this answer, since the other ones now appear to be **wrong**.

Comment: I'm struggeling with this topic as well, although it's clear to me what attributes and params are. I have a whole model class like in (C) and I would've expected that adding it to the model and then forwarding would bind it to the new model in the second controller too. But it isn't. It's on request scope in the second controller, but not bound to the model attribute of the same name (parameter in the second controller). So, obviously binding only takes into account params, not attributes.

Comment: When we add attributes to the request, in the case of forward, the entire URI is persisted throughout the flow? So, I need not add the attribute again at any time? What about in the case of a redirect? @Bogdan

Answer (score 0):

Consider forward just like redirect but without the need for a context and host in this sense (forward is handled internally by the server, whereas redirect instructs the user's browser to request a different url).

So, yes, use the session, cookies or post or get parameters.

Comment: The request already has its own parameters... I want those to go with it as well. But I'd also like the Model and perhaps there are other ways to send data?

Comment: Have you tried adding ModelMap to your controller and adding your new values to that for the forwarded controller to use?

Comment: I think you should go with the session approach. It's the simplest work around. Unless you can push on the new attributes via the GET or POST parameters.

Comment: Wow, I'll be surprised if using the session is the best way to do this. You'd think Spring would provide a better forwarding framework.

Comment: I think it's more a limitation of Java servlet api and request scope.

Comment: Have you found an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered filters? You could create a filter using the delegating  filter proxy which will gives you access to the request parameters as well as the spring beans .

Comment: Can you elaborate or point me to an example? I don't see how that fits together.

Comment: @Tony . I was given the option of redirecting the request and trying to change the parameters using a filter . If you want to use forward , you ma want to use session attributes.

Comment: I cant see how that would work. From what Tony has said so far I doubt there is anything in the request attributes he needs.

Answer (score 0):

I've found [**this post**](http://www.ocpsoft.org/opensource/how-to-safely-add-modify-servlet-request-parameter-values/), that uses an `HttpRequestWrapper`:

**First:**
Define the `HttpRequestWrapper` and override the methods `getParameter`, `getParameterMap`, `getParameterNames` and `getParameterValues` like in the post.

**Second:**
Forward via RequestDispatcher to your url, using the *wrapped* request in the method parameters:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("myForwardUrl").forward(new MyRequestWrapper(request), response);
```

I've tried this out for deleting of parameters (which is even more difficult!) and it works!