# SPRING BOOT - JAVA : Add client parameter to the URL

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-boot

I want to add a client name parameter to my URL, so when i receive a link like : 
http://localhost:8080/client1 i want to test if my client is present in database, if so i want that the client receive the content of my site like if he call :
http://localhost:8080/

I tried to do this with a wrapper like indicated here :

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
public class ChangeURIPathFilter implements Filter {
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ChangeURIPathFilter.class);
    RequestWrapper modifiedRequest = null;
    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {}
    @Override
    public void destroy() {}
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        String contextPath = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getContextPath();
        String requestURI = httpRequest.getRequestURI();
        modifiedRequest = new RequestWrapper(httpRequest, "/");
        chain.doFilter(modifiedRequest, response);
    }
    class RequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {
        private String originalValue;
        public RequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request) {
            super(request);
        }
        @Override
        public String getRequestURI() {
            String originalURI = super.getRequestURI();
            String s = super.getRequestURI();
            if (StringUtils.equals(s, originalValue)) return originalValue
                .replaceAll("client1", "");
            else return s;
        }
        public RequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request, String newValue) {
            super(request);
            this.originalValue = request.getRequestURI();
        }
    }
}
```

But all my tests failed. Can any one help me to resolve this ?

Thanks

Comment: I can't understand your question. Please explain more

Comment: See the following answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8585216/spring-forward-with-added-parameters

Comment: I have a saas application, which serve multiple clients. I want to give to each client a link to access my application like : localhost:8080/client1. If the client is not present i will forward it to a error page. I see this behavior in  https://www.zoho.com/bugtracker/   Thanks, im waiting for your response.