# SPRING forward with params

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm trying to forward the request to another controller.
It seems to forward correctly but another controller doesn't get the parameters I specified.
Here's my code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String registerUser(@RequestParam("name") String name,
                           @RequestParam("email") String email,
                           @RequestParam("pswd") String password,
                           HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
    try {
        manager.getTransaction().begin();
        User user = new User();
        user.setName(name);
        user.setEmail(email);
        user.setPassword(password);
        manager.persist(user);
        manager.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        manager.getTransaction().rollback();
        request.setAttribute("errorMessage", e.getMessage());
        return "forward:/error";
    }
    request.setAttribute("email", email);
    return "forward:/main";
}
```

The other controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/error")
public ModelAndView throwError(@RequestParam (value = "errorMessage") String errorMessage) {
    return new ModelAndView("error", "errorMessage", errorMessage);
}
```

The error that I get is (in browser):

```
HTTP Status 400 - Required String parameter 'errorMessage' is not present
```

So the question is why does the request not contains the `errorMessage` attribute? What is wrong?

Comment: did you try to set method to RequestMethod.POST even on /error controller?

Comment: Shouldn't it be  return "forward:/error?errorMessage="+e.getMessage();

Comment: Andrea Girardi, yes, I've tried - still doesn't work.

Comment: Obi Wan - PallavJha, I've tried this way too - doesn't work

Comment: @ObiWan-PallavJha solution just seems to work:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8585216/spring-forward-with-added-parameters