# Forward request to spring controller

Tags: spring-mvc, servlets, spring-rest

From a servlet , I am forwarding the request to a spring controller like below

```
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/myController/test?reqParam=value");
rd.forward(request, response);
```

In order to pass a parameter to the spring controller  , I am passing it as request parameter in the forward URL.

Is there a better way of doing this ?

Instead of passing in request parameter , can I pass as a method parameter to the spring  controller during forward ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring forward with added parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8585216/spring-forward-with-added-parameters)

Comment: May I ask - do you have to make this call from a pure Java servlet?  That is, why not a controller?

Comment: I am already in the context of a servlet ( I cannot change much code in this servlet ) . I need to forward the request to a controller where I can enrich the response before sending back to browser

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will be called when `/myController/test?reqParam=value` is requested:

```
@RequestMapping("/myController/test")
public String myMethod(@RequestParam("reqParam") String reqParamValue) {
  return "forward:/someOtherUrl?reqParam="+reqParamValue;  //forward request to another controller with the param and value
}
```

Or you can alternatively do:

```
@RequestMapping("/myController/test")
public String myMethod(@RequestParam("reqParam") String reqParamValue,
                       HttpServletRequest request) {
  request.setAttribute("reqParam", reqParamValue);
  return "forward:/someOtherUrl"; 
}
```

Comment: The OP is calling from a servlet, not another spring controller. I don't think you can use the `"forward:...."` trick in that case?

Comment: Hmm, ok. Wasn't clear to me that it had to be from a servlet or whether that was just how OP went about it.

Comment: Thanks .  Will try this out.

Answer (score 1):

you can use path variable such as follow without need to use query string parameter:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/mapping/parameter/{reqParam}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String byParameter(@PathVariable String reqParam) {
    //Perform logic with reqParam
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Will try this out