# Forward request to a Spring MVC controller from a Servlet

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, servlets, forward

How can I forward a request to a Spring MVC controller from a **Servlet** (or **Servlet Filter**)?

I cannot use the following because I am not inside a Spring MVC controller:

```
return "forward:/target-url";
```

Neither the following would work:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("forward:/target-url").forward(request, response);
```

Comment: I believe this is not a duplicate of [Forward request to spring controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42465091/forward-request-to-spring-controller) because the accepted answer shows how to forward from a *Spring MVC controller*, not from a Servlet.

Comment: Your second snippet should work, it is also documented example in Baeldung, could you explain what you mean by "does not work", provide the log if there is an error ? Or see where the request is landing instead ?

Comment: I don't do Spring, but `forward:` prefix is not part of standard Servlet API at all. So you'd better just remove it. `getRequestDispatcher("/target-url")` is the standard Servlet API approach. Try that first instead of trying to use Spring-specific ways in a non-Spring related class.