# Spring Mvc Request forwarding

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

```
@RequestMapping("/modify")
public String modifyAd(AdDto adDto, Model model){
    if (adService.modifyAd(adDto)){
        adDto.setTitle("");
        model.addAttribute(PageCodeEnum.KEY,PageCodeEnum.MODIFY_SUCCESS);
    }else {
        model.addAttribute(PageCodeEnum.KEY,PageCodeEnum.MODEFY_FAILED);
    }
    return "forward:search";
}
```

The adDto.title I got from jsp is '芒果冰淇淋11',

I have set Title to ""

[image: debug before forward]

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String queryByTitle(AdDto adDto, Model model){
    List<Ad>adList = adService.queryByTitle(adDto);
    model.addAttribute("adList",adList);
    model.addAttribute("searchParam",adDto);
    return "/content/adList";
}
```

But after forward, `adDto.title` doesn's change. I don't know why.

[image: debug after forward]

You can see the 'title' change to "芒果冰淇淋11"

Comment: What do you mean doesn't change? How do you know it's not changed? Are you checking in jsp? You've to put up everything. Your information isn't enough

Comment: i can see the value of 'title' in debug

Comment: Maybe its not the same object?

Comment: i know, i just want to find the way to get the adDto.title changed

Answer (score 0):

I think this response on another question may be helpful:

[Spring forward with added parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8585216/spring-forward-with-added-parameters)

re-adding what you need to the request before it is forwarded.

Using FlashScope as well should be an option here an example:

https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/02/spring-mvc-flash-attributes.html

(in the example it uses "redirec:some/path" but using "forward" as you do should be possible as well)

A link to Spring (4.1) docs for Flash attributes:
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-flash-attributes

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved this problem in adding the following code:

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoNSw.png)